# Referring to a proper noun

Tags: pronouns

I am writing an analytical compare and contrast/map the crisis essay, and I was wondering about the ambiguity of pronouns in my thesis.

Which of these is correct?

> T.S. Eliot depicts Thomas Becket’s idée fixe through his existential journey to reject the pernicious ideals of the State for the Glory of the Church.

Or

> T.S. Eliot depicts Thomas Becket’s idée fixe through Becket's existential journey to reject the pernicious ideals of the State for the Glory of the Church.

Also, I feel as if the use of 'for' in

> to reject the pernicious ideals of the State for the Glory of the Church.

is misplaced, what would be a better replacement to show a shift in loyalty?

If anybody is curious, this is regarding Eliot's 'Murder in a Cathedral,' and the prompt is to write a 'compare and contrast' essay that answers the question 'what does it mean to live a truly meaningful life' and maps the development of a character's existential crisis.

Answer (score -1):

Use passive voice to reduce the ambiguity.

> Thomas Becket’s idée fixe is depicted through his existential journey to reject the pernicious ideals of the State for the Glory of the Church by T.S. Eliot.

Comment: However, if seems as it 'T.S. Eliot' now modifies 'the Glory of the Church' or similar, is there a way we could move the author's name?